# Peer to peer ipsec tunnel - virtual network interface

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipsec, ifconfig

I'm trying to create an IPSEC tunnel between two machines (**not** between two networks). Using ipsec-tools, TUNNEL mode.

I think I can cope with all those `add` and `spdadd`, but **how to create a virtual network interface for the IPSEC tunnel ?** I want some services to listen (and initiate connections) on that virtual interface (just like all other VPNs designed).

I think I should do something like `ifconfig <something> 10.1.1.1 up`... then my services will listen on that 10.1.1.1 and the other machine will use, say 10.1.1.2 and will connect using that interface. IPSEC will take the packets, encapsulate them etc.

Sane IPSEC documentation is something I were unable to find, and after so much trial and error I'm about to give-up.